# using python3 and django, how do I push into JSON DICT object

Tags: python, json, django

I am using Django Views to publish Views.

```
def index_view(request):
    enlisted = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("E").active().count()
    officer = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("O").active().count()
    civilian = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("C").active().count()
    lifer = models.Subscription.objects.lifer().active().count()
    subscriptions = models.Subscription.objects.all().order_by("-Modified")
    statembr = models.Member.objects.values('State').annotate(c=Count('State')).exclude(State='')
    statembrmap = dict([(type_and_count['State'], type_and_count['c']) for type_and_count in statembr])
    stateunit = models.Unit.objects.values('State').annotate(c=Count('State')).exclude(State='')
    stateunitmap = dict([(type_and_count['State'], type_and_count['c']) for type_and_count in stateunit])
    ctryunit = models.Unit.objects.values('Country').annotate(c=Count('Country')).exclude(Country='')
    ctryunitmap = dict([(type_and_count['Country'], type_and_count['c']) for type_and_count in ctryunit])
    ctrymbr = models.Member.objects.values('Country').annotate(c=Count('Country')).exclude(Country='')
    ctrymbrmap = dict([(type_and_count['Country'], type_and_count['c']) for type_and_count in ctrymbr])
    units = models.Unit.objects.values('Unit_name', 'Hull_type', 'Hull_number').annotate(c=Count('memberunit__Member'))
    context = {'ctrymbrmap': ctrymbrmap, 'statembrmap': statembrmap, 'enlisted': enlisted, 'officer': officer,
               'civilian': civilian, 'lifer': lifer, 'units': units,
               'Subscriptions': subscriptions, 'statunitmap': stateunitmap, 'ctryunitmap': ctryunitmap}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

if you see the variable `context`, It's hardcoded. Is there a way to "Push" into the `context` variable, to allow dynamic construction of said variable?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

`context.update({'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'})`

or

```
context['key1'] = 'value 1'
```

Comment: how do I start context?  context = {}?

Comment: Ya.... you declare a dictionary and `.update(<dictionary_object>)` pushes a dictionary object in your existing dictionary.

Comment: ok.  so there in lies the issue.  If I use a dict.  The templating is refusing to acknowledge the variable.  for example, the first variable `ctrymbrmap` is no longer existing.  How do I compensate?  Thanks

Comment: nvm.  This works.  Just mispelled a variable.  THANKS MUCH.